# peer server cannot open two socket services at the same time

Tags: node.js, websocket, server, peer

I want to add a socket service to the peer server service again, is this theoretically possible?
For example, I could customize a server and then add the processing of a different url to the server's *upgrade event* to have it mapped to a different socket service.
Here is my implementation of why **wss.handleUpgrade** does not work. If it doesn't work in theory, please tell me exactly why

```js
import { PeerServer } from 'peer'
import ws from 'ws'

function createServer() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    PeerServer({path: '/foo'}, server => {
      resolve(server)
    })
  })
}
function withEditorRtcServer(ws, req) {
  // not working
}

const server = await createServer()

const wss = new ws.Server({ noServer: true })
wss.on('connection', withEditorRtcServer)
server.on('upgrade', (request, socket, head) => {
  if (request.url === '/bar') {
    wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, (ws) => {
      wss.emit('connection', ws, request)
    })
  }
})
```

I also tried the proxy approach

```
import http from 'http'

const server = http.createServer()
```